# Select data with condition multiple like

Tags: mysql, sql

Example :

Product

```
 |  PK(AI)  | product_id | product_part |
 |          |     1      |     bolt     |
 |          |     1      |     gear     |
 |          |     2      |     bolt     |
 |          |     2      |     steel    |
```

Then I try select product_id where product_part have (bolt **and** gear)

I trying

```
`SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_part LIKE '%bolt%' AND product_part LIKE '%gear%'` 
and result is nothing. should be result is product_id 1.
```

NOTE : it's must have 2 **not** either (OR)

Comment: Either GROUP BY, or self join, or EXISTS/IN.

Comment: Do you really want LIKE here? Do you want to include boltsy, steel cap shoes etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use grouping like this:

```
SELECT product_id  
FROM product 
WHERE product_part LIKE '%bolt%' OR product_part LIKE '%gear%'
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN product_part LIKE '%bolt%' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN product_part LIKE '%gear%' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

This way you can select `product_id` values being related to *both* '%bolt%'-like and '%gear%'-like `product_part` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an INNER JOIN on the same table:

```
SELECT p1.product_id FROM product AS p1
INNER JOIN product AS p2 
ON p1.product_id = p2.product_id
WHERE
p1.product_part LIKE '%bolt%' AND
p2.product_part LIKE '%gear%'
```

Comment: Nice answer but it's not combine to 1 table, Thx

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What you mean @Newbi ? :)

Comment: when i try the query it's not combine (the results is not 1 field) it's 2 field result with (1 field for bolt word and 1 field for gear word)

Comment: Actually this query retrieves every product_id related to both bolt and gear.